# Java Date-Time format confusion

Tags: java

I have a date-time string like `2013-10-23 10:10:04.0`. I'm kind of confused by what the extra zero signifies at the end of the string?

Does it denote the time zone or something else? I saw documentation on the different characters for the Java DateTime format, but I'm not sure what it is in the string above?

Comment: i think that's for the milliseconds. zones will show something like EST or PT at end of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ussually, the date time format is denoted by

yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S   where S (the last part of the format) are the milliseconds, in this case, .2 whould be 200 milliseconds.

Taje a look at [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) docs, and the patterns

Answer (score 2):

It's milliseconds.

The format for the date is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`, where `S` is the millisecond.

So `.002` would be two milliseconds and `.200` would be two hundred milliseconds.

Comment: So `.2` would be 2 milliseconds?

Comment: It would have to be `.002` for two milliseconds. I don't think you can ever get `.2`, it would be `.200`.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember it's milliseconds